# Is it possible to setTag() on a resource AKA an int?

Tags: java, android, tags

I have this image that I want to set a tag too, but is it even possible to set a tag on an int?

Example:

```
int bacon = R.drawable.bacon;
bacon.setTag("xxx");
```

Answer (score 1):

Primitive types are not objects.  They don't have methods.  So, no, it's not possible unless you use the wrapper class (`Integer`).  And even then, `Integer` doesn't have a `setTag()` method.

Comment: So would there be no possible way to set a tag to an image?

Comment: @Piofmc I don't really know what you're trying to accomplish.  But if your image is an object of a class which has a `setTag()` method, then yes, you could invoke `setTag()` on it.

Comment: Well, what I want to do is to set a tag to an image, so that on different image buttons I can retrieve that tag specific to that image.

Comment: your intentions are honorable, but R.drawable.bacon is not an image but an identifier, a number... Besides, tags are a property of View, so you'll need to build a ImageView, load in your bacon, then add the tag. (imageView=new ImageView(context) -> imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.bacon) -> imageView.setTag("crunchy bacon")

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution could be to have the image in an ImageView and then setTag() on the view.